# Get pdf download location from URL query

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have a PDF download location which is formatted as follows:

https://www.example.com/apps/user_name?txtFile=directory_1%2Fmy_pdf_file.pdf

Which NSURL would I need to pass to for example NSURLSessionDownloadTask in order to download this mentioned PDF (my_pdf_file.pdf)?

UPDATE:
The problem seems to be related to the url redirection to a different location, which is unknown at the outset.

Further info:

- I have no problem downloading files formatted as http://www.example.com/my_pdf_file.pdf
- I'm using AFNetworking for downloading files
- My download code is as follows:

  ```
      NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
      AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
      NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
          NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
          return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
      } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
          if (!error) {
              DDLogInfo(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
          }
      }];
      [downloadTask resume];
  ```

Comment: The URL which directly downloads or opens the pdf in the browser.. (I know this sounds vague but you have not provided any other info about whether the URL you have mentioned redirects to the file locations or whether it has authentication etc...)

Comment: It's not too vague, I understand ;)
I just figured out that the url is indeed redirecting, and most likely using a form of authentication. This would make it quite difficult.
I was hoping it was possible to distill the PDF URL from the query, but this is not the case

Comment: AFNetworking is quite capable of handling both *redirection* and *authentication challenges* .. however, if you are planning to trigger this in background you may have to come up with a better solution for authentication as there will be no user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

In order to download a PDF file using `NSURLSession` do the following:

```
NSString *londonWeatherUrl = @"https://www.example.com/apps/user_name?txtFile=directory_1%2Fmy_pdf_file.pdf";
```

First here is how you make this call when using NSURLConnection:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:londonWeatherUrl]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                       NSData *data,
                       NSError *connectionError) {
      // handle response
}];
```

Now let’s use NSURLSession. Note that this is the simplest way to make a quick call using NSURLSession. Later in the tutorial you will see how to configure the session and setup other features like delegation.

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:londonWeatherUrl]
          completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                              NSURLResponse *response,
                              NSError *error) {
            // handle response

  }] resume];
```

Comment: This would be the case with normal URLs. However this does not work when the pdf link is mentioned in the query parameters.

Comment: @FreekSanders This is the way to download PDF with NSURL as you have asked. Maybe the problem is that the url that you specify is not of the PDF file, instead it opens a PDF viewer. Is that the case? Can you post the PDF url so we can see it?

Comment: The problem is that the URL is redirected, and the redirections points to the PDF file. It's a normal PDF file and opens as such when downloaded using Safari. Unfortunately the redirected URL is behind an authentication wall, which makes testing a lot harder.